# Modifying global variables in scheme

Tags: global-variables, scheme

I have a basic character rotation algorithm, and I need to store the user input into a global variable named key. How can I modify key with a user inputted value?

```
;Global variable to be modified 
(define key 0)

;encryptor
(define encrypt
  (lambda(str)
    (+ key (read))
    (list->string(map encryptor (string->list str)))

    )

  )


(define encryptor
  (lambda (ch)
    (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
    (rotator ch)
    ch
    )
  )
  )

;char incrementor that utilizes the key.
(define rotator
  (lambda (ch)
    (integer->char(+ (char->integer ch) key)
                  )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Use `set!` to modify global variables. But you should avoid using global vars in the first place! that's not the style of programming encouraged by Scheme, try to solve the problem in a functional programming style.

Comment: You don't need a global variable, you need another function parameter.

Comment: Rather than having a global variable write a function which, given a key as an argument, returns a function which encrypts using that key.

Comment: As a side note, I personally found that using the "closing bracket on a new line" habit made understanding lisp-y languages more difficult. I think it could be because they look like a "block structure" that's true in other languages but doesn't make sense in the lisp-y world. The conventional layout became a convention because it makes a lot of sense, not because it's short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a global variable, you need to restructure your functions.

Separate user interaction from processing (this is a good idea in general) by making the key a function parameter.

```
(define (encrypt key str)
    (lambda(str)
        (list->string(map (lambda (ch) (encryptor key ch)) (string->list str)))))


(define (encryptor key ch)
    (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
            (rotator key ch)
        ch))


(define (rotator key ch)
    (integer->char (+ (char->integer ch) key)))


;; Example use:
(let ((key (read))
      (input (read)))
    (encrypt key input))
```

To get an encryption function that encapsulates the key, make a function that produces a function where the key is "captured" (this is sometimes called a "closure"):

```
(define (encryptor key ch)
    (lambda (ch)
        (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
                (rotator key ch)
            ch)))
```

Example:

```
> (define crypt-1 (encryptor 1))
> crypt-1
#<procedure>
> (crypt-1 #\a)
#\b
> (crypt-1 #\b)
#\c
> (crypt-1 #\1)
#\1
```

Now you can simplify `encrypt`:

```
(define (encrypt key str)
    (list->string (map (encryptor key) (string->list str))))
```